# Using viewpager for scrolling children inside a view

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

I have a menu which looks like this http://flashspeaksactionscript.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/vert-menu18.jpg Considering the `child` as that "3" in the picture I would like to be able to swipe that "3" to the left and see be able to see another item.

Here's my xml code:

```
         <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Sum"
                style="@style/SummaryButtons"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="Item 1" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nana"
                style="@style/SummaryButtons"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="Item 1" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mama"
                style="@style/SummaryButtons"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="Item 1" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/example_get_by_id"
            android:layout_width
```

etc. These are the children. For example I want to be able to swipe through these buttons, just because I cannot use `HorizontalScrollView`because my application is consisted of fragments and already has a swipe ability to surf through fragments. The swipe ability for those fragments and `HorizontalScrollView` get mixed up so, that's why I need to be able to use `Viewpager` for single items and not the whole page. Is there any at least an example for this? I couldn't find anything.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look this may be useful to you:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageArra);
  ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
  myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
  myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
 }

 private int imageArra[] = { R.drawable.gallery_photo_1, R.drawable.gallery_photo_2,
   R.drawable.gallery_photo_3, R.drawable.gallery_photo_5,
   R.drawable.gallery_photo_6, R.drawable.gallery_photo_7,
   R.drawable.gallery_photo_8, R.drawable.ic_launcher };

}
```

and ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Activity activity;
int imageArray[];

public ViewPagerAdapter(Activity act, int[] imgArra) {
    imageArray = imgArra;
    activity = act;
}

public int getCount() {
    return imageArray.length;
}

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
     ImageView view = new ImageView(activity);
      view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
      view.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
      view.setBackgroundResource(imageArray[position]);
      ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}
}
```

xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/myfivepanelpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >

    </ImageView>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it is working fine i tried already now i attached xml file also once you can try...

Comment: hi again, I tried it and it almost worked, but as soon as I swipe to go to the next picture, the application crashes. why would that be?

Comment: It does not put the images side by side but they are all in the same place

Comment: what is your requirement do you want to view all images on screen at a time or you want to view single single image by swpping images?

Comment: just now i updated the code, now you will not get any exception